# Scope of an object within a Pyramid function

Tags: python, scope, pyramid

I am struggling to understand the scope of request and request.db in the following decorated python function (this function is part of the Pyramid "Todo List Application in One File" tutorial):

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
    request = event.request
    settings = request.registry.settings
    request.db = sqlite3.connect(settings['db'])
```

I thought assignments in a function were limited in scope to that function unless declared as a global;  so according to my flawed understanding, request and request.db would go out of scope when the function completes.  But in this case I am clearly mistaken because request.db is accessed subsequently within other functions.  Could somebody explain the genesis and scope of the magic object's request and request.db please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request` is really just a local alias to `event.request`. That function could be rewritten as follows:

```
def new_request_subscriber(event):
     event.request.db = sqlite3.connect(event.request.registry.settings['db'])
```

So all we're doing is modifying the attributes of the `event` object that's passed in. Since Python passes the actual object, the modifications will be seen by whatever called the function.